# Como substituir letra digitada em python?

Tags: python

ola a todos eu quero desenvolver um script que faça a substituição de uma letra digitada por outra , então ficaria assim a = e , b = f .

fiquei algum tempo tentando criar um algoritmo para essa função mas o interpretador só substituia uma letra de uma vez , no caso eu gostaria de fazer isso para toda a frase.

```
y = []
x = raw_input('reading: ')
print(x)
for i in x:
    if (x) == 'a':
        x = str('e')
        y.append(str('e'[0]))
        if (x) == 'b':
            x = str('f')
            y.append(str('f'[1]))
            if (x) == 'c':
                x = 'g'
                y.append(x[2])
                if (x) == 'd':
                    x = 'h'
                    y.append(x[3])
                    if x == 'e':
```

acima um pedaço do codigo. sei que há formas melhores mas ainda sou iniciante .. eu estava em duvida em usar o while ou for , peço que me orientem.

Comment: Você pode usar dicionários para associar cada letra.. Ficaria : { "a":" e" , "b" : "f" ...} .. Ai depois só transformar a string digitada em lista e para cada elemento pegar o correspondente no dicionario.. Transformando novamente pra string..

Comment: Seus comandos if estão erradamente encadeados. Estude a cláusula else.

Answer (score 8):

> Lembrando que em Python 3, usa-se `input` no lugar de `raw_input`. Como a pergunta utiliza o segundo, assumiu-se que refere-se a Python 2.

A melhor forma é utilizando o método `translate` do objeto *string*:

```
from string import maketrans

table = maketrans('abcd', 'efgh')

x = raw_input("Reading: ")

print(x.translate(table))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/PersonalLoyalGames)</sup>

A função `maketrans` constrói a tabela de conversão, indicando no primeiro parâmetro os caracteres que serão substituídos e, no segundo parâmetro, os caracteres que serão inseridos, respectivamente.

Você pode ainda utilizar o método [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) dos objetos *string*:

```
x = raw_input("Reading: ")

x = x.replace("a", "e")
x = x.replace("b", "f")

print x
```

Para uma entrada `abcba`, a saída gerada é `efcfe`.

```
>>> Reading: abcba
efcfe
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HdDh/2)</sup>

Se forem muitas letras, pode utilizar a dica do [Marlysson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/627/marlysson), nos comentários:

```
letters = {
    "a": "e",
    "b": "f",
    "c": "g"
}

x = raw_input("Reading: ")

for l in letters:
    x = x.replace(l, letters[l])

print x
```

A saída seria:

```
>>> Reading: abcba
efgfe
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HdDh/1)</sup>

Você ainda pode fazer um código análogo utilizando compressão de listas:

```
letters = {
    "a": "e",
    "b": "f"
}

x = raw_input("Reading: ")

x = "".join([letters[l] if l in letters else l for l in x])

print x
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HdDh)</sup>

Comment: Só pra complementar, o último exemplo também poderia ser `x = "".join(letters.get(l, l) for l in x)`

Answer (score 1):

Ressuscitando o tópico...Mas quem ainda tiver alguma dúvida de como fazer isso, acredito que um algoritmo de rotação de caracteres([Cifra de César](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_C%C3%A9sar)), em alguns casos, pode mais fácil e mais dinâmico do que o **maketrans** ou um **de/para** de strings:

```
import string

rot = 4
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
alphabet_length = len(alphabet)

text = raw_input("Digite a frase: ")

result = []
for letter in text:
    if letter.lower() in alphabet:
        unicode_point = ord("a") if letter.islower() else ord("A")
        start = ord(letter) - unicode_point            
        offset = ((start + rot) % len(alphabet)) + unicode_point
        result.append(chr(offset))
    else:
        result.append(letter)

print "".join(result)
```

Ex:

```
Digite a frase: abcde
efghi
```

Comment: Não é mais dinâmico. Na cifra de César vc avança uma quantidade fixa (se "a" for trocado por "e", então "b" necessariamente terá que ser trocado por "f"), já o `maketrans` permite qualquer combinação (poderia trocar "a" por "e" e "b" por "x", e as demais letras não mudam, por exemplo - na verdade não se limita a letras, pode ter qualquer caractere trocado por qualquer outro). Nesse ponto, `maketrans` é bem mais dinâmico.